# SDL/SDL_mixer.h: No such file or directory -compilation terminated?

Tags: c++

I have zero experience with Linux.

Please kindly help me with error I'm getting whilst trying to compile this application:
http://winpe.com/gascop/

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd Downloads/gascop
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads/gascop $ qmake-qt4
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads/gascop $ make
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -D_REENTRANT -Wall -W -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -
DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -
I/usr/include/qt4/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -I. -o mainwin.o mainwin.cpp
In file included from mainwin.cpp:29:0:
mainwin.h:38:27: fatal error: SDL/SDL_mixer.h: No such file or directory
#include "SDL/SDL_mixer.h" ^ compilation terminated.
Makefile:254: recipe for target 'mainwin.o' failed
make: *** [mainwin.o] Error 1
```

I have installed both libsdl-mixer1.2-dev and SDL2_mixer_devel but it seems like compilator cannot allocate these.

How to deal with that?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: `SDL/SDL_mixer.h: No such file or directory` The error seems pretty clear to me. If you have SDL installed, then make sure that you are pointing the compiler to the path containing its headers.

Comment: Hi Cody, many thanks for your reply, would you kindly explain how to point the compiler to the path containing its headers?

Comment: From the page:
Gascop depends on qt4, _sdl and sdl_mixer._
`sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev`
Should be the command assuming this application uses SDL**2**.
If it's not SDL2, this or some variation of this should install version 1.2
`sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev`

Comment: Hi Christopher, thanks for your reply. Both libsdl2-dev and libsdl1.2-dev are installed already.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone still searching for solution, following worked for me:

```
sudo apt install libsdl1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev
```